# Hive: Unable to create external tables for existed data in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, bigdata

**Update 1**:
Modified the version of `hadoop` to 2.x but the error is still there.

**Original**:

I generated `tpcds` test data into Ceph with `hive-testbench`.

Currently, the data is located at root directory of storage system, and is in folder `tpcds`.

For example, the result of `hdfs dfs -ls /` is

```
drwxrwxrwx   - root root          0 2019-08-05 10:44 /hive
drwxrwxrwx   - root root          0 2019-08-05 10:44 /tmp
drwxrwxrwx   - root root          0 2019-08-05 10:44 /tpcds
drwxrwxrwx   - root root          0 2019-08-05 10:44 /user
drwxrwxrwx   - root root          0 2019-08-05 10:44 /warehouse
```

The result of `s3cmd ls s3://tpcds` is:

```
                   DIR   s3://tpcds/hive/
                   DIR   s3://tpcds/tmp/
                   DIR   s3://tpcds/tpcds/
                   DIR   s3://tpcds/user/
                   DIR   s3://tpcds/warehouse/
```

For `s3cmd ls s3://tpcds`, the bucket name is `tpcds`.

When the data is ready, the next setup is to create external table in `Hive` to get access to those data. The reason why I show the storage layout is to make sure by you guys that the issue I met has nothing to do with the path.

The command used is `hive -i settings/load-flat.sql -f ddl-tpcds/text/alltables.sql -d DB=tpcds_text_7 -d LOCATION=tpcds/7`, however, I met issue below:

```
 exec.DDLTask: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Exception thrown flushing changes to datastore)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createDatabase(Hive.java:433)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createDatabase(DDLTask.java:4243)
```

For the stack version: `Hive 2.3.2`, `Hadoop 3.1.2`.
Currently, the most possible reason from my side is about the hadoop version, I'm going to degrade it to hadoop 2.7 to see if same error occurs.

And at the same time, any comment is welcomed. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue is solved, I'd like to post the solution here for further visitors who might meet same issue.

The `hive` I used to initialize schema of `mysql metastore` is `3.1.1`. After that, I just replaced the hive folder with `hive 2.3.2`. This kind of downgrade is not graceful, the metastore created before is not consistent with `hive 2.3.2` and that's the reason why I met the issue.

I reverted the hive folder to `3.1.1` and everything turns fine.